# Scrapy: Associate scraped data from different links to 1 Item/Model

Tags: python, scrapy

Consider that I have 3 links `A`, `B`, `C`:

`A` and `B` are links to web pages and `C` is a link to a file which needs to be downloaded.

My scraper curently does this:

1. from page `A`: extract metadata, extract link to page `B`
2. from page `B`: extract download link `C`
3. from `C`: download/save file

*Note1*: I use 3 different [`Rule`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.Rule)s to extract the `A` links, `B` links and `C` links

**The Problem**
The problem is that, I don't know how to associate an item (metadata from page `A`) with the downloaded file from link `C`.

Currently an item is created in the parse callback method of the `Rule` for the `A` links and the file is saved in the callback method for the `C` links

An Item and/or a Model, (I use SQLALchemy for storing in DB, using pipelines) needs to contain the metadata + the name of the downloaded file.

Does anyone has an idea about **how to associate the metadata with the name of the downloaded file?**

*Note2*: I use the Rule system since it can be easily extended with new rules and the rules can be reused in other spiders.

Comment: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this approach is approximative:

```
def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)

    if response.url = 'link_to_A':
        i = new Item()
        i['meta_1'] = sel.xpath('//selector')
        i['meta_2'] = sel.xpath('//selector')

        link_to_B = sel.xpath('//selector')

        yield Request(url=link_to_B, meta={'item': i})

    elif response.url = 'link_to_B':
        i = response.request.meta['item']
        i['link_file'] = sel.xpath('//selector')

        return i
```